# Middle mouse button won't paste 'primary' selection

Tags: mouse, gnome-terminal

I have just installed Ubuntu 17.10 as a guest Virtualbox system. I'm trying to use the standard terminal, and I'm having the issue that the middle mouse button pastes clipboard contents, and not the 'primary' selection. Is it normal behavior for this terminal? If yes, how can I change it and make the middle button paste 'primary' selection?

Comment: "Is it normal behavior for this terminal?" – No. Middle button pastes primary for me, just as Shift+Insert. What does Shift+Insert do for you? Unfortunately at this point I have no clue what could be different on our systems.

Comment: @egmont Shift+Insert inserts the clipboard, and not the selection. Even worse, I can't copy anything to the clipboard from the terminal. Shift+Insert inserts only what has been copied previously from another program (i.e. Firefox). To put it clearer: 1) Shift+Ctrl+C in terminal seems to do nothing; 2) Shift+Ctrl+V/Shift+Insert/Middle button insert the clipboard copied from another program

Comment: Could be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/1722121 (how do you start up gnome-terminal? are you on x11 or wayland?), or maybe Virtualbox is missing you.

Comment: @egmont It's wayland. Virtualbox works just fine with Debian where I use X11. So I'd assume it's wayland problem.